# YAML configuration reads properties wrongly

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, yaml

I'm trying to set up a configuration in Spring Boot to store specific times to perform some actions, for which I have the following `application.yml`:

```
hour: 14:00
```

And my configuration properties file:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
public class CcScheduleConfig {

    private LocalTime hour;

}
```

But running the application throws this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Integer] to type [java.time.LocalTime]
```

Apparently it is parsing `14:00` as an `Integer`. How is that even possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have Spring Boot parse properties bound to LocalTime in ISO8601 format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61911328/how-to-have-spring-boot-parse-properties-bound-to-localtime-in-iso8601-format)

Comment: @birca123 nope. The problem is Spring is taking somehow `14:00` as an integer, so a String to LocalTime converter is never used. But the integer value does not make any sense (it takes `14:00` as 840), so I can't either use a converter from Integer to LocalTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of YAML's (many) quirks. It treats the value `14:00` as an integer, expressed as the the number of minutes in 14 hours and 00 minutes which is `840`. Similarly, `12:57` would be `777`.

You can avoid the problem by wrapping the value in quotes:

```
hour: "14:00"
```

The quotes tell YAML to essentially leave the value alone. It will then be passed as-is into Spring Boot's conversion service which will be able to turn `"14:00"` into a `Localtime`.

Comment: I know about the quotes. I was trying to find a way to make it work without them as well. I think your explanation will work. How did you know how YAML takes time as the number of minutes? I failed to find that information in the documentation...

Comment: It's not very well specified, but there's [an example in the spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id858600) that shows that a integer value containing a colon should be treated as sexagesimal (base 60). [Here's the code in SnakeYAML](https://bitbucket.org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml/src/f75151daf2b18b68205010587fdbec8889b5ede8/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/constructor/SafeConstructor.java#lines-279:286) that implements this behaviour. If you want to avoid quotes, the only other option that I am aware of is to tag the value as a string: `hour: !!str 14:00`

Comment: thanks for your time! You completely solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

You can inject it like an integer and after convert using `LocalTime of()`
method from  `java.time.LocalTime`
YAML:

```
localtime:
  hour: 14
  minute: 00
```

Comment: how? `14:00` is injected as `840`

Comment: localtime:
  hour:
  minute:
After it your java config class will have 2 int params, you will pass to the LocalTime.of(hour,minute).  I  edited my answer i am sure it will be more helpful

Comment: but it is not an option to divide hour and minute. It must be together

Comment: it will be together after `LocalTime of()` i dont think that is an problem to use my propose, just try it.